How to step into C source code when debugging Rust on VSCode?
In my Rust project, I have a module called user.rs that defines an FFI for some C functions. This is a simplified version of what that looks like:
#[cfg(target_os = linux)]
#[link(name = "my_lib", kind = "static")]
extern "C" {
    pub fn some_c_function(arg: u16) -> u8;
}

pub fn complex_function() {
    let foo = unsafe { some_c_function(3) };

    // Some implementation ...
}

I was trying to debug a segmentation fault that occurs when calling some_c_function() using VSCode. To do that, I added a breakpoint to the line that makes the external function call. However, when I try to step into the function, I get the following error screen:

How can I make the debugger find the appropriate source code and allow me to continue the debugging process?
Here's what the debug configuration inside launch.json looks like:
{
    "name": "my_app_debug",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/my/exec/file",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": false,
    "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "setupCommands": []
}

It is important to note that I have local access to the C source files. If it's of any help, I'm currently on stable Rust v.1.77.2 running on Debian 12.7.0.

Starting with the obvious: was the library compiled with debug information? If you debug a C program that calls the same function, can you step into it there? Alternatively, did you strip the debug symbols and move them into a separate file where gdb can find them? If this is a library installed from your package manager, see if you can get a -dbg variant installed.
